# Is it possible to upload Lumia Living Images to OneDrive, instead of just the static image?

Tags: windows-phone, onedrive, lumia-imaging-sdk, lumia

I have a windows phone and I am trying to upload the Lumia Living Images taken with Lumia Camera. Looks like there is no option to upload the Living Image directly to OneDrive, but only the static images.

So wondering if there is any api available so that I can create an app to upload the images to OneDrive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to [using a Windows Phone](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com), and not developing software for them.

Comment: I have clearly asked if there is an API to upload living images . I believe its relevant to developing software but not to using Windows Phone..

Comment: As far as OneDrive is concerned, it's just a regular file, and doesn't need special handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked everywhere, at this point of time there is no api to upload Living Images to OneDrive. I guess this will change soon. In the new windows 10 mobile insider preview, they recently added support for gif images support for photos app. Probably at some point when Windows 10 Mobile comes RTM we might have native support for Lumia Living Images.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special API to do this, as the living image portion is tacked inside the JPG file, which is then viewable using the Photos app on Windows 10 (or any other capable client).